# Application of the cube lemma

Tags: ct.category-theory, dg-categories

In the paper [Spherical DG-functors](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5035.pdf), the authors introduce the notion of twisted cubes and prove a lemma that they call "The cube lemma". One of the applications they prove is the following, given a pretriangulated DG category $\mathcal{C}$ and a diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 A @>f_{AB}>> B\\
 @Vf_{AC}VV  @Vf_{BD}VV\\
 C @>>f_{CD}> D
\end{CD}
$$
of closed morphisms of degree zero, such that $f_{BD}f_{AB} + f_{CD}f_{AC} = -df_{AD}$, where $f_{AD}: A \rightarrow D$ is a morphism of degree -1, then in $H^0(\mathcal{C})$ we have an octahedron
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 a @>f_{ab}>> b @>>> cone(f_{ab})\\
 @Vf_{ac}VV @Vf_{bd}VV @VVV\\
 c @>f_{cd}>> d @>>> cone(f_{cd})\\
 @VVV @VVV @VVV\\
 cone(f_{ac}) @>>> cone(f_{bd}) @>>> t
\end{CD}
$$
where every triangle is exact, and every square commutes up to a sign.
Am I corret in deducing that given any category $\mathcal{D}$ which admits a DG enhancement $\mathcal{C}$ and any diagram 
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
 a @>f_{ac}>> b\\
 @Vf_{ac}VV  @Vf_{bd}VV\\
 c @>>f_{cd}> d
\end{CD}
$$
in $\mathcal{D}$ which commutes up to a sign, then there exists a diagram as above? And moreover, is it correct that 
$$
cone(cone(f_{ab}) \rightarrow cone(f_{cd})) \simeq cone(cone(f_{ac}) \rightarrow cone(f_{bd}))
$$
independently of the map chosen to complete the morphisms between the distinguished triangles? (This last question is probably the same as asking whether any such morphism can be realized by a triple $(f_{AB},f_{AD},f_{CD})$ ).